# How to spider a password protected site in python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

currently I have a spider written in Java that logs into a supplier website and spiders the website. (using htmlunit)

It keeps the session (cookie) and even lets me enable/disable javascript etc.

I also use htmlparser (java) to help parse the html and extract the relevant information.

Does python have something similar to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to crawl pages, which supports password authentication and cookies.

There is also a [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) for extracting html, but some people prefer the more feature-full [BeatifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: What's _really_ cool is that it'll be about one-millionth of the amount of Java code you had to write ;)

Comment: indeed, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: before using BeautifulSoup check out lxml, its a **much** better/faster general parser, BeautifulSoup is good for pocket cases and munged HTML, it can also be embedded in the lxml API as well. If you go the BS route :) get version 3.0, version 3.1 is absolute junk.

Answer (score 1):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) API uses urllib2 plus adds wires up some different parsers and helper routines.